# Stuck at os.rename can't quite figure out how to tie it in with the rest of my script

Tags: python

I am new to programming and python and this is my first program I decided to try and tackle.

This loops through my files in the directory that I run it from and takes out the string of text I don't want and leaves me with the file name I would like (in theory).
 It all works except the problem I am stuck with is that  I can not figure out how to get `os.rename` (I think that is what  I need to use) to work from inside my loop.

I have read up on it but I guess I just don't get how to tie it in.
I'm using python 2.7.
This is what I have got so far:

```
import os

file_count = 0

for files in os.listdir('.'): #Open for loop in the current dir.
    if files.find('_The_Hype_Machine_') and files.endswith('.128.mp3') :
        mod_list = list(files) #Turns filenames into a list so they can be edited
        del(mod_list[-38:-4])  #specifies the piece of string I need taken out of each filename.
        files =''.join(mod_list) #Turns the list back to a string
        file_count += 1 
        updated_file = files.replace('_', ' ') 
        os.rename(files, **"not sure what goes here"**)

        print updated_file
        print 'Your modifed MP3 File Count: ', file_count;
```

I could use some direction and Help with understanding if anyone is up for it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to edit the question, but I'm not sure the indenting is as your original. Please check it, thanks.

Comment: `files.find('_The_Hype_Machine_')` will return **-1** - which is **true** in a boolean context - when `_The_Hype_Machine_` is not present in the name. It will return 0 - which is **false** in a boolean context - when it appears right at the beginning. If you want to know whether `_The_Hype_Machine_` can be found `in` the string, that's exactly what you should test: `'_The_Hype_Machine_' in files`. Incidentally, it would make more sense to use a singular name (e.g. `file`) for that variable: *at any given time*, it stores *one* file name.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few tweaks to your program, and annotated it with instructional comments:

```
import os

# Each time through the following loop, "afile" will take on the next file name
# also we can use "enumerate" to give us a file_count as we go (instead 
# of tracking the count separately)
# In general, we shouldn't change a list we're iterating over, so we'll save it off
file_list = os.listdir('.')  # (as sk4x0r mentioned)
for file_count, afile in enumerate(file_list): #Open for loop in the current dir.  

    # using the 'some_string' in some_text is more typical python useage
    if '_The_Hype_Machine_' in afile and afile.endswith('.128.mp3'):

        # Now, strings are immutable, so we can't exactly remove the 
        # inside of a string
        # What we can do is create a brand new string composed 
        # of everything we want to keep
        new_name = afile[:-38] + afile[-4:]

        updated_file = new_name.replace('_', ' ') 
        os.rename(afile, updated_file)

        print updated_file
        print 'Your modifed MP3 File Count: ', file_count
```

Comment: Thank you sk4x0r and Gerrat,both of your answers have helped me understand a smidge more of programming and python and I was able to finish my file edit.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems to the variable *updated_file* contains new name for the file.
If you are fine with new name of the file you are generating you can do:

```
os.rename(files, updated_file)
```

Also note that your check

```
if files.find('_The_Hype_Machine_') and files.endswith('.128.mp3') :
```

might not work fine. The **files.find** invocation returns a -1 when substring is not found in the string and index of the substring of the substring when it is found. So it is better to rewrite the above conditional as:

```
if files.find('_The_Hype_Machine_')!= -1 and files.endswith('.128.mp3') :
```

Also it would be better if you choose a different variable name than 'files' say something like:

```
for my_file in os.listdir('.'):
```

using *files* as the variable name gives the impression that it refers to all files returned by **os.listdir**, where as it is just name of a single filename used for current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if everything above `os.rename` works fine, then `os.rename(files, updated_file)` should give the expected result. But in general, updating the contents of list while iterating through it is not considered safe. So with some modification in your code, I could come up with this code:

```
    import os
    file_count=0
    files=os.listdir('.')
    for f in files:
        if f.find('_The_Hype_Machine_') and f.endswith('.128.mp3'):
            f2=f[:-38] #cuts last 38 characters from filename including extension .mp3
            f2=f2.replace('-','_')
            os.rename(f,f2) #I guess, f2+'.mp3' should be more correct
            file_count+=1
```